# Por que não temos uma funcionalidade de seguir pessoas ou pesquisar pessoas?

Tags: novo-recurso, status-recusado

Eu gostaria de poder seguir pessoas interessantes e saber o que elas estão fazendo ou procurar por elas na caixa de pesquisa.
Lideres de comunidade, pessoas de destaque, é interessante acompanhar as respostas que elas estão dando. 
O RSS é interessante, mas tenho que sair do site para isso.

Comment: Altamente relacionado: http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/1361/o-sopt-se-encaixa-na-categoria-de-rede-social

Comment: Procurar por usuários você sempre pode, em http://pt.stackoverflow.com/users

Comment: Acho esta uma ótima sugestão. Embora não sejamos uma rede social, a ideia de ser notificado de informação gerada por determinadas usuários é bem interessante, já que algumas pessoas costumam gerar conteúdo de excelente qualidade com o qual é possível aprender bastante.

Comment: @bfavaretto, entendi... e concordei! Realmente não somos uma rede social e por mais que seja interessante seguir pessoas não é o foco!
Nesse caso removo esse post?

Comment: Independente da opinião canônica, o pedido de novo recurso é válido. Se não for atendido, dá para quebrar o galho com extensões do browser como http://stackapps.com/questions/4454/stackeye-chrome-extension-to-follow-users-and-questions-on-stackexchange-sites e http://stackapps.com/questions/1863/follow-your-friends-on-stackoverflow-with-friendoverflow (@utluiz, vale uma olhada).

Comment: Brandão, se não se incomodar com isso, deixa o post aí. É bom pra sentir o que a comunidade pensa (aviso, você deve levar uns votos contra, mas [no meta isso não conta](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/1668/significado-do-voto-no-meta) :)

Comment: Na verdade, o voto contra aqui no Meta também conta como "não estou de acordo". Como previsto pelo @bfavaretto, aqui fica meu -1 :P

Comment: `seguir pessoas interessantes e saber o que elas estão fazendo` Stalker detectado.